# Winforms VS2008 Interface to property in Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I would like to bind a user created component to a property of my user control in my vs2008 designer.

Here's the setup:

```
    namespace ns1
    {
        public interface ISource
        {
             string Read();
        }

        public class Dummy:Component, ISource
        {
            public Dummy()
            {
            }

            public string Read()
            {           
                return "DummyString";
            }    
        }     

        public partial class DataShow: UserControl
        {
            public ISource Source {get; set;}
            public DataShow()
            {
            }
        }     
    }
```

Now i can create and add the Dummy to the property from the vs designer.
However if i create a class that inherits both interface and component(To show in toolbox) in an other namespace. I can't assign this class to my property.

I can do this from code. How can i do this from designer. As the other class is also shown in toolbox and inherits the same interface.

Code from the object i cant select but create is :

```
    namespace ns2
    {
        public class ActualSource:Component, ISource
        {
            public ActualSource()
            {
            }

            public string Read()
            {
                return "ActualData";
            }

        }
    }
```

Also this object appears in my toolbox. But when it's created i cant select it on the usercontrol to assign it to the property. The second class is created in the project that contains my form and logic to read from my source. The ns1 is in my imported library.

Comment: Post the code you are having a problem with instead of code that works just fine.

Comment: There is a bug in that snippet you added, it must implement ns1.ISource, not just plain ISource.  So it appears that you have *more* than one ISource declaration.  And no, ns1.ISource is never compatible with ns2.ISource, the CLR treats them like distinct types.  So does the designer.  Change it to `ns1.ISource` and you'll see that it now works just fine.

Comment: Hans,

I've changed the code from the 2nd class to ns.ISource. However it's still not possible to do this in the designer. Also in the Toolbox i have 2 tabs. The first is telling me SCADAOBjects Components(NS1) with the items Dummy and DataShow. The 2nd tab is telling PLC_Communication Components(NS2) with only the Actual source

Comment: Any ideas on this? ?